# R - add column checking occurrence of something in last n rows of column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, dplyr, lag

I want to create a new column where at each row TRUE is returned if a certain value is found within the last n rows of another column, and FALSE is returned otherwise.

Here is an example dataframe (suppose this is a sample from a much larger dataframe):

```
A
2
23
1
5
6
15
14
3
7
9
55
3
77
2
```

And here is what I want (where conditional value=1 and n=10)

```
A   B
2   FALSE
23  FALSE
1   FALSE
5   TRUE
6   TRUE
15  TRUE
14  TRUE
3   TRUE
7   TRUE
9   TRUE
55  TRUE
3   TRUE
77  TRUE
2   FALSE
```

I can do this with many "OR" conditions in an ifelse statement in dplyr:

```
df<-df %>% mutate(B=ifelse(lag(A)==1|lag(A,2)==1 ... |lag(A,10)==1,T,F))
```

But this is far too tedious, especially when n is large. Also, lag in dplyr only takes integers so `lag(A,1:10)` doesn't work.

Is there an easy way to do this (preferably without a for loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, `lag` from `dplyr` does not allow you to pass a vector as shift amount, but the `shift` function from `data.table` allows you to do so, which has the same functionality as `lag` and `lead` in `dplyr`, so you can use `shift` from `data.table` with a `Reduce` function to do that:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, B := Reduce("|", shift(A == 1, n = 1:10, fill = F))]
df
     A     B
# 1:  2 FALSE
# 2: 23 FALSE
# 3:  1 FALSE
# 4:  5  TRUE
# 5:  6  TRUE
# 6: 15  TRUE
# 7: 14  TRUE
# 8:  3  TRUE
# 9:  7  TRUE
#10:  9  TRUE
#11: 55  TRUE
#12:  3  TRUE
#13: 77  TRUE
#14:  2 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this in `dplyr` with `do` and `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    do(data.frame(., B= Reduce(`|`, shift(.$A==1, n = 1:10, fill = 0)))) 
#   A     B
#1   2 FALSE
#2  23 FALSE
#3   1 FALSE
#4   5  TRUE
#5   6  TRUE
#6  15  TRUE
#7  14  TRUE
#8   3  TRUE
#9   7  TRUE
#10  9  TRUE
#11 55  TRUE
#12  3  TRUE
#13 77  TRUE
#14  2 FALSE
```